# Connect on MacBook through HTTP to VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, html, macos

I have been stuck on this for ages, I am running VirtualBox from my macbook. The virtualBox has Enterprise Linux 5 installed on it. What I am trying to do is execute php scripts on my virtual box from the mac side through objective c. Does anyone know how I can execute these php scripts through HTTP? So on the MAC side using Google chrome I am typing this into the address bar: 192.168.0.13 (this is the ip of my virtualbox) and all I get is this:

Index of /

Name
Last modified
Size
OLAP_XDS/
Sat, 02 Oct 2010 18:29:56 GMT

-

XFILES/ 
Fri, 21 Oct 2011 00:20:54 GMT

-

home/
Fri, 21 Oct 2011 18:48:02 GMT

-

olap_data_security/ 
Thu, 13 Aug 2009 23:17:56 GMT

-

public/ 
Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:28:12 GMT

-

publishedContent/
Fri, 21 Oct 2011 18:48:27 GMT

-

sys/
Fri, 21 Oct 2011 00:14:49 GMT

-

xds/
Thu, 13 Aug 2009 23:17:56 GMT

-

How can I see the php scripts on the virtual box and execute them on the VirtualBox server?

Thanks
Michael Williams

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which webserver you're using...

You have to install and enable PHP within your webserver.

Comment: Yes Apache is installed and PHP enabled.

Comment: Place your php file (ex. test.php) in the document root of your apache. Ensure user/permission of that file and browse to http://192.168.0.13/test.php